# Return object from a webworker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

```
var worker = new Worker('./src/parser.js');

  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.data.getCollection()); // .. is not a function
  };
```

The worker:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  var myModel = new Model();
  myModel.readFile(e.data.files[0], function (data) {
    console.log(myModel.getCollection()); // Returns array
    postMessage(myModel);
  });
};
```

The instansiated object is returned but only the values in the constructor. Not any prototype functions.

Why? Isn't it possible to return an instansiated object from a webworker?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that all data passed to and from the web worker is serialized (JSON parse / stringify). The func definitions on the object would get erased during serialization.

Instead of returning the model, could you return the queried array instead?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: No. it's a huge class-schema I'm parsning and I need to be able to check inheritance (instance of..).

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do quite what you want. Instead, you'll have to architect the web worker interaction in a way where it can do all the queries / calculations it needs to do in response to a message ... and give a message in response that is just data. It might be useful to think of the worker as essentially another server that you can receive messages from. You can't really send "functions" as a web request to communicate with the server, but you shouldn't need to either.

Comment: Yeha, gonna have to think of another way. Thx.

Comment: Can confirm, functions are not transfered. Since I have the class definition on both sides, I am wondering what is the best way to transfer the "content" into a newly created object. Especially if I have nested Objects with functions.